# Comparing/Sorting elements and then squaring them using an array list with O(n) complexity

Tags: java

I have a nested loop that loops through every element in the list comparing it/sorting it , then I am trying to square the numbers in the list(keep in mind they need to be sorted). The problem is when I run my program, the 'test' array list that I am using does not print the last one squared, but it prints the second to last one squared twice. For example, if my array list is (1,2,3,4,5) my code should print (1,4,9,16,25) but instead it prints (1,4,9,16,16). I can't seem to figure out why.

My code:

```
public static void sortSquares(List<Integer> tempList) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = tempList.size() - 1; j > i; j--){
                if (tempList.get(i) > tempList.get(j)) {
                    result = tempList.get(j) * tempList.get(j);
                }
                else if (tempList.get(j) > tempList.get(i)) {
                    
                    result = (tempList.get(i) * tempList.get(i));
                    
                }
        
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last external loop when `i = 4`, the inner loop becomes:

```java
for (int j = 4; j > 4; j--)
```

which does nothing, and the outer loop prints `result`, which contains the previous value (16).

The solution could be to replace the condition for the inner loop to `j >= i`. You also need to replace the condition of the `if`, as `tempList.get(j)` will now be equal to `tempList.get(i)`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
   for (int j = tempList.size() - 1; j >= i; j--){
      if (tempList.get(i) > tempList.get(j)) {
         result = tempList.get(j) * tempList.get(j);
      }
      else if (tempList.get(j) >= tempList.get(i)) {
         result = (tempList.get(i) * tempList.get(i));
      }
   }
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

It will work for (1,2,3,4,5).

That being said, the same result could be attained with a simpler code:

```java
Collections.sort(tempList); /* Optional, if you want to sort the result */
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
   result.add(tempList.get(i) * tempList.get(i));
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thankss for the help!, One more small question, if I wanted to convert the output so it prints like this: [1,4,9,16,25] instead of creating  a new line, how would I go for that?

Comment: I updated the example. You just have to put all the result in an ArrayList, and the output will be exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solution won't work if `tempList[i] == tempList[j]`.Replace `else if` with `else` and it will work.

Comment: Thankss for the help!, One more small question, if I wanted to convert the output so it prints like this: [1,4,9,16,25] instead of creating a new line, how would I go for that?

Comment: You can keep a string and append to it. `String s = "["`. Instead of  `System.out.println(result)` you can do `s += i == tempList.length - 1 ? result + "]" : result + ","` and `System.out.print(s)` at the end.
You can optimise it further using `StringBuilder`  class for appending in the string.